# How to view the name of an item with a tooltip that extends offscreen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

In Hypixel Skyblock, sometimes the item has so many enchants and such long descriptions that it can't fit in the screen and only shows the bottom part of the description and enchants, excluding the stats sometimes and usually the name of the item. Since in Hypixel Skyblock there are a lot of different bows, but all of them look the same, how do I tell what is what?

Answer (score 1):

A simple, albeit annoying, solution is to decrease your GUI scale.

Go to `Options` -> `Video Settings` and change `GUI Scale` to `Small`.

There are also mods available that allow you to scroll tooltips. These include:

- [Tooltip Scroll](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/tooltip-scroll-fabric) (Fabric)
- [Scrollable Tooltips](https://sk1er.club/mods/text_overflow_scroll) (Forge 1.8.9)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use the texture pack which all those Hypixel sub YouTubers use that have different textures for different bows. Or if you are me, use lunar because they have scrollable tooltips there.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! When you are answering people on this website, make sure to use proper grammar and sound more professional; remember, this isn't like Reddit! :)